# Amazon rekognition EyesOpen errors

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm looking to use Amazon rekogintion to detect whether an eye is closed or not
its working perfectly except for when testing on people who wear eyeglasses, which give false info with a (weirdly enough) a high confidence level note that im using high res images to test this out, is there anything that can be done to fix this?